# How to use cookies in pinia stores in Nuxt3

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, cookies, nuxt.js

I made a Pinia Store in my Nuxt3 Application Frontend. I want to use cookie that is assigned maxAge=user.expiryIn, so when cookie expires, it should call repo.refreshToken() function to get a new bearerToken, the function and api calls are all done, but i dont know how to assign cookie and watcher to invoke function.

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import repo from "~/repositories/index";
import { getUserImage } from "~/utils/helperFunctions";
import { useStorage } from "@vueuse/core";

export const useUserStore = defineStore("user-store", {
    state: () => ({
        email: useStorage("email", ""),
        img_url: useStorage("img_url", ""),
        refreshToken: useStorage("refreshToken", ""),
        bearerToken: useStorage("bearerToken", ""),
        expiryIn: useStorage("expiryIn", 0),
        domains: useStorage("domains", []),
    }),

    actions: {
        async login(email: string, password: string) {
            try {
                console.log("here");
                const data = await repo.user.login(email, password);
                if (data != null) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                    console.log("Success");
                    this.$state.email = email;
                    this.$state.img_url = getUserImage(email);
                    this.$state.bearerToken = data.bearerToken;
                    this.$state.expiryIn = data.expiryIn;
                    this.$state.refreshToken = data.refreshToken;
                    this.$state.domains = data.domains;

                    console.log("bearerToken " + this.$state.bearerToken);
                    console.log("email " + this.$state.email);
                    console.log("expiryIn" + this.$state.expiryIn);
                    console.log("refreshToken" + this.$state.refreshToken);
                    console.log("domains" + this.$state.domains);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    console.log("[UserStore] [Login] Login Failed");
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("[UserStore] [Login] " + error);
                return false;
            }
        },
        logOut() {
            console.log("[UserStore] [LogOut] Logging out");
            this.$state.email = "";
            this.$state.img_url = "";
            this.$state.bearerToken = "";
            this.$state.expiryIn = 0;
            this.$state.refreshToken = "";
            this.$state.domains = [];
        },
        setEmail(email: string) {
            this.$state.email = email;
        },
        setImgUrl(img_url: string) {
            this.$state.img_url = img_url;
        },
        setRefreshToken(token: string) {
            this.$state.refreshToken = token;
        },
        setBearerToken(token: string) {
            this.$state.bearerToken = token;
        },
        setDomains(domains: any) {
            this.$state.domains = domains;
        },
    },
    getters: {
        getEmail: (state) => state.email,
        getImgUrl: (state) => state.img_url,
        getRefreshToken: (state) => state.refreshToken,
        getBearerToken: (state) => state.bearerToken,
        getDomains: (state) => state.domains,
    },
});
export default useUserStore;
```

Comment: Does the cookie uses HTTP only and set secured to true?

Comment: @ReaganM well I havent worked with cookies so I dont know much. Doing frontend for the first time.